# Will a PLB (Personal Locator Beacon) work overseas?

Tags: europe, personal-locator-beacons

I'm starting to do some solo hiking here in Italy, and I'm going to buy a PLB soon. I was wondering if I went to Germany or Australia for example, if I activate the beacon will the beacon still get me the emergency services I would need? Thanks!

Comment: Please note that you should try to use cellular services first, if available, as you'll be able to give much more precise information about your situation. When not in some depressed area surrounded by mountains on all sides, I've often had coverage in the Alps.

Comment: According to the data provided by the accepted answer, the result is ambiguous, and you should be careful and act under the assumption that the German authorities may **not** heed your beacon. Be careful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call would be routed to the international [COSPAS-SARSAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Cospas-Sarsat_Programme) network.

Here are the Beacon Regulations Handbooks for each country: http://www.cospas-sarsat.int/en/documents-pro/beacon-regulations-handbook

They have an **INCOMPLETE** and somewhat contradictory summary of countries: http://www.cospas-sarsat.int/en/beacon-ownership/national-beacon-regulations-for-serial-coded-plbs

Comment: This is interesting. Thank you. However, even after looking up Germany in the "Beacon Regulations Handbooks for each country" link you provided, I'm still confused: if you take a serial-coded PLB with you to Germany and use it (let's assume you were unaware of this restriction), will you receive emergency services (end then possibly be fined), or will they just ignore you because yours is serial-coded? Ie: "Serial-coded PLBs are not allowed in Germany"

Comment: Yeah @Loduwijk I was pondering on the same question myself :)  I guess Herr Hauptmann would get an alert, come over, fine you and drive back home ;) Seriously though - I reckon you would not have ANY rescue at all. I would be conservative and assume it to be this way.